# how to resolve rename error when insalling grunt via npm without admin access?

Tags: permissions, installation, file-permissions, npm

I need to install grunt for a project setup in Windows 7. However, I am running into an issue that whenever I try to install grunt globally, it fails because of a permission error.

A few other people had this problem and a few others do not, the error that comes up is

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, rename (insert npm global module path here)\grunt\node_modules\grunt-legacy-log-utils' -> '(insert npm global module path here)\grunt\node_modules\.grunt-legacy-log-utils.DELETE'
```

Asking for admin permissions to install software is not allowed where I am at.

Comment: have you tried `npm cache clean` as suggested [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10826#issuecomment-165124144)

Comment: yes, also I got admin access to run the command.

The same error still comes up, even with the messaging saying to run as admin when I was running as admin.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was resolved by repeatedly doing `npm cache clean` and `npm install`.

Also we also had an issue with node-sass because it couldn't reach github to download a binary.